# Iridium ORM - cannot create relationships. (

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm, xamarin.forms

I'm working on an Xamarin app as a learning exercise but I cannot for the life of me get relationships mapping correctly/working as expected. Iridium has been my chosen ORM as it supposedly supports relationships and custom types better than standard SQLite. 
I've created a separate console app to try debug this but again have hit a wall. Can anyone help point out what i'm missing? or is there something fundamental I've overlooked with Iridium/ relationships/Types or ORM in general?

NuGet: iridium.db.sqlite

```
class Model
{
    [Column.PrimaryKey(AutoIncrement = true)]
    private int _ID;
    public int ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; } }

    [Column.Null]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private List<ChildModel> _object;
    [Relation.OneToMany]
    private IEnumerable<ChildModel> _Objects
    {
        get { return _object; }
        set  { _object = value.ToList(); }
    }
    public List<ChildModel> Objects
    {
        get { return _object; }
        set { _object = value; }
    }

    public Model()
    {
        _object = new List<ChildModel>();
    }

}


class ChildModel
{
    [Column.PrimaryKey(AutoIncrement = true)]
    private int _ID;
    public int ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; } }

    [Column.Null]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public ChildModel()
    {

    }
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbContext = new StorageContext(new SqliteDataProvider("mydbTest.sqlite"));

        // Create tables (if they don't exist) yet
        dbContext.CreateTable<Model>();
        dbContext.CreateTable<ChildModel>();

        //generate test data
        Model model = new Model {Name ="Test" };
        model.Objects.Add(new ChildModel { Name = "first" });
        model.Objects.Add(new ChildModel { Name = "second" });
        model.Objects.Add(new ChildModel { Name = "third" });

        //Save Test Data in DB.
        dbContext.Insert(model, obj => obj.Objects);


        //TODO: read test data once we know it stores properly...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Exception/Stacktrace?

Comment: No exception thrown, it just seems to ignore the method call entirely. I can individually insert both classes.but not together. and when I open the .sqlite file to see it's structure the relationship columns aren't setup. The iridium documentation states the related entities primary key should be automatically used as the foreign key but nothing happens.  - Worried i might have to manually map it all which could get messy and complicated. There must be a wayaround/gotcha somewhere though. seems fairly fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model classes should be a lot simpler. Also, ChildModel needs a foreign key pointing to the parent Model:

```
class Model
{
    [Column.PrimaryKey(AutoIncrement = true)]
    public int ID { get;set; }

    [Column.Null]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Relation.OneToMany(ForeignKey="ParentID")    
    public List<ChildModel> Objects {get;set;} = new List<ChildModel>();
}

class ChildModel
{
    [Column.PrimaryKey(AutoIncrement = true)]
    public int ID { get;set; }

    public int ParentID {get;set;}

    [Column.Null]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```